# google-oauth : Invalid grant error

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm new using oauth 2.0, so I followed the tutorial from google to access Analytics using oauth 2.0
I created an OAuth client in the google developers console and I used this code to access analytics:

```
  httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
      dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
      // authorization
      Credential credential = authorize();

      // set up global Oauth2 instance
      oauth2 =
          new Oauth2.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
              APPLICATION_NAME).build();


      Analytics analytics = new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
```

The authorize method:

```
 private static Credential authorize() throws Exception 
  {
    // load client secrets
    clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(OAuth2Sample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter") || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/ "
          + "into oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("[my email]");
  }
```

And I download the JSON file from the Auth 2.0 client that I create in the google developers console:

```
 {
    "installed":
    {"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "client_secret":[my clients secret],
    "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","oob"],
    "client_id": [my client id],
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
    }
    }
```

I rund the code and the result is:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Do you know if I missing something? 
Thank you very much for your help!